# Rewrite Java class to clean and testable code

Tags: java, oop, polymorphism, refactoring

So I have a Java class that looks like this:

```
class CalendarEntry {

    private char type;

    private char status;

    ...


    public void myMethod() {
        switch (type) {
            ...
        }
    }

    public String myOtherMethod() {
        switch (status) {
            ...
        }
    }

    // and so on

}
```

Type and status are two different attributes/flags. Both can have more than 3 different condition set.

If I would only have one of these "flags" I could easily refactor the code using polymorphism and dropping all swtich cases and if else blocks that really make the code a big mess.

But now I have something like >= 3x3 different conditions comming from two totaly different flags. What would be the best approach to refactor this kind of code?

Comment: What are `type` and `status` even meant to represent? It sounds like they should be enums, to start with...

Comment: This might be better suited to http://codereview.stackechange.com.

Comment: It would be closed on CodeReview as it is not a complete code sample. It is pseudocode/hypothetical code from what we can see here and thus would be off-topic unless OP provided the real-life implementation of his code (rather than just a few bits and pieces).

Comment: Type would be something like 't' for todo or 'e' for event, status would be  like 'c' for closed etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a real status and type, then you can apply the next logic. Classes are mostly reflections of a type, with some behaviour and properties that depends on the type. (For example `Animal`,  `Cat extends Animal` and `Dog extends Animal`). Status will say something about that type, like for example `Status.AWAKE`, `Status.SLEEPING`. The status does not change the type of the class, but rather a bit of its behaviour.

So:
`type` is an excellent candidate for polymorphism (if it really denotes a type)

`status` should be an enum/other class that lives in all subclasses. Status says nothing about the thing that is being talked about.

Each subclass can implement their own `myOtherMethod`, or, if the status-based-method is always the same, implement it in the superclass.

On the other hand, if the `type` and `status` (and their behaviours) have nothing in common, they should be separate classes and have nothing do to with each other. But deducing from the question I think thet are somehow related.

Comment: Your assertion that both are somehow related is true, so I think the first aproach you mentioned would be a good point to start with